# Dúvida no SELECT ao criar uma VIEW

Tags: postgresql

Boa tarde pessoal,

estou precisando criar uma VIEW no POSTGRESQL, exemplo abaixo:

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW teste.nomedaview AS
SELECT **tabela1.cpf**
FROM teste.tabela1
UNION
SELECT tabela2.cpfcnpj
FROM teste.tabela2;
ALTER TABLE teste.nomedaview

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Na minha tabela1 existem 2 colunas, a coluna cpf que possui somente cpf e a coluna cnpj que possui apenas cnpj;

Na minha tabela2 existe uma só coluna chamada cpfcnpj que possui ou cpf ou cnpj;

Nessa view acima, como está sendo utilizado o UNION, para que essa informação venha em uma só coluna, tem alguma maneira de unificar essas informações da tabela 1 (cpf com cnpj)? tipo quando a coluna cpf estiver preenchida ele pegue as informações dela e se a cnpj estiver preenchida ele pegue as informações dela

**OBS 1: no exemplo acima (em negrito) quando coloco somente umas das informações (cpf ou cnpj), a view é gerada, porém nela só vai aparecer os cpfs da tabela1, mas no caso eu queria que aparecesse cnpj também;
OBS 2: na tabela1, quando a coluna cpf estiver preenchida, quer dizer que a coluna cnpj vai estar nula, e vice-versa;
OBS 3: em ambas as tabelas essas colunas são do tipo "character varying".**

alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: o ideal por normalização é não usar campos que podem sofrer alteração com chave estrangeira, também seria bom usar a chave primaria única. tb_exemplo1.id = tb_exemplo2.id, tb_exemplo3.id = tb_exemplo2.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde,

Acredito que você pode utilizar a função *Coalesce* para obter o valor da coluna que estiver preenchida entre as colunas cpf e cnpj:

```
SELECT coalesce(tabela1.cpf, tabela1.cnpj) as cpfcnpj 
FROM teste.tabela1

UNION 

SELECT tabela2.cpfcnpj 
FROM teste.tabela2
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Bom dia, ajudou sim! funcionou perfeitamente, grato!